# Maybe monad in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, monads, option-type

I'm playing with a Maybe monad in TypeScript. My understanding of the concepts isn't great so I would welcome any feedback or suggestions. There are loads of JS examples, but I'm looking for something more strongly typed.

The usage would be something like:

```
var maybe = new Example.Maybe({ name: "Peter", age: 21 })
    .ifF(p => p.age === 100)            // is the person 100?
    .returnF(p => p.name, "Unknown")    // extract Maybe string of name
    .getValue();                        // unwrap the string from the Maybe
```

Because if/with/return are reserved words I have just added F to the end..

So far I have:

```
module Example
{
    export class Maybe<T>
    {
        private val: T;
        private hasv: boolean;

        private static none = new Maybe(null);

        constructor(value: T)
        {
            this.val = value;
            this.hasv = (value != null);
        }

        /** True if Maybe contains a non-empty value
        */
        hasValue(): boolean
        {
            return this.hasv;
        }

        /** Returns non-empty value, or null if empty
        */
        getValue(): T
        {
            if (this.hasv) return this.val;
            return null;
        }

        /** Turns this maybe into Maybe R or Maybe NONE if there is no value
        */
        withF<R>(func: (v: T) => R) : Maybe<R>
        {
            if (!this.hasv) return Maybe.none;
            return new Maybe<R>(func(this.val));
        }

        /** Turns this maybe into Maybe R or Maybe DefaultVal if there is no value
        */
        returnF<R>(func: (v: T) => R, defaultval: R): Maybe<R>
        {
            if (!this.hasv) return new Maybe(defaultval);
            return new Maybe<R>(func(this.val));
        }

        /** If func is true, return this else return Maybe NONE
        */
        ifF(func: (v: T) => boolean): Maybe<T>
        {
            if (!this.hasv) return Maybe.none;
            if (func(this.val))
                return this;
            else
                return Maybe.none;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is good. Only a few minor suggestions.

## JS DOC

Prefer

```
/** True if Maybe contains a non-empty value */
```

for single line JSDoc comments and

```
  /** 
    * True if Maybe contains a non-empty value
    */
```

for multiline ones

## Other implementations

There is also a codeplex issue : https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/2585 with implementation : https://gist.github.com/khronnuz/1ccec8bea924fe98220e < this one is focusing on iteration where as your's is focusing on continuation

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend referring to the fantasyland spec when constructing these things. WithF is generally called filter, returnF/withF can be replaced by map/chain. orJust is another method that allows you to provide a default value if your flow returns nothing.

```
var maybe = new Example.Maybe({ name: "Peter", age: 21 })
    .filter(p => p.age === 100)
    .map(p => p.name)    
    .orJust('unknown');
```

https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land

There is much less to think about when you implement functionality according to the spec. You can also switch to a different data type (such as array/list) fairly easily as the methods will exist on the new type as well.

Comment: When looked at the original function names, wasn't so sure what they are doing, so I had to read their implementation to understand their job. With your code it very clear what they are doing even without looking at their implementation. Nice job!